# WKWebView is not working with JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, swift, html, oop, wkwebview

I am working on a project with WKWebView and I have the html loading from the local project. JavaScript is working as expected, but when I try to use a class it makes the WebView just appear blank.

I have tried using ES6 syntax and ES5 syntax they both cause the same problem. Is there a way to use JavaScript classes in a local html file in WKWebView? If there is what am I doing wrong?

This is my code for the WebView application

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let webView = WKWebView()
let remoteAccess = false
let url = "Website/index"

override func loadView(){

    if(remoteAccess){
        loadWebView(string: url)
    }else{
        loadLocalWebView(string: url)
    }

    self.view = webView
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true;
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func loadWebView(string: String){
    if let url = URL(string: string){
        let request = URLRequest(url: url);
        webView.load(request)
    }else{
        print("Failed to connect to URL: " + string)
    }
}

func loadLocalWebView(string: String){
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: string, withExtension: "html"){
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
    }else{
        print(string + "not found!")
    }

}
}
```

this is the code for the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Local Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="index.css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <script>

        var display = new Display(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        var ctx = display.create();
        function render(){
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        render();

        function Display(width,height){
            this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            this.canvas.id = "canvas";
            this.canvas.width = width;
            this.canvas.height = height;
        }

        Display.prototype.create = function(){
            document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
            this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            return this.ctx;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `return ctx;` in `Display.prototype.create` function should probably be `return this.ctx;`.

Comment: @amn your right, i fixed that but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem, was that I was defining the class after creating the instance, which caused nothing to work, after flipping the order, everything worked.